# What is User Defined Data Type in Informix?

Tags: informix

What is User Defined Data Type in informix? How to Create that?
I am unable to find any documents for that.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following diagram:

```
http://informix.hcldoc.com/help/topic/com.ibm.udr.doc/ids_udr_128.htm
```

It shows the different data types you can have in Informix.

You can get more information about how to write and use User Defined Type (UDT) in the "User-Defined Routines and Data Types Developer's Guide"

```
http://informix.hcldoc.com/help/topic/com.ibm.udr.doc/udr.htm
```

You can find a basic example of a simple UDT in the $INFORMIXDIR/extend/krakatoa/examples directory:

```
* A user-defined type called "circle" implemented partly in Java

    Circle.java
    circle.h
    circle.c
    Circle.sql 


Directory of D:\Infx\ids12\extend\krakatoa\examples

20/03/2017  10:21    <DIR>          .
20/03/2017  10:21    <DIR>          ..
21/01/2017  20:22               743 circle.c
21/01/2017  20:22               231 circle.h
21/01/2017  20:22               880 Circle.java
21/01/2017  20:22             1,237 Circle.sql
21/01/2017  20:22             1,716 Env.java
21/01/2017  20:22               696 Env.sql
21/01/2017  20:22             1,401 JDBC.java
21/01/2017  20:22               435 JDBC.sql
21/01/2017  20:22             1,607 LO.java
21/01/2017  20:22               437 LO.sql
21/01/2017  20:22            11,013 Logger.java
21/01/2017  20:22             1,806 README
21/01/2017  20:22                91 run.bat
21/01/2017  20:22               343 runbld.bat
```